# How to build "Star Rating" report in BigQuery (or sparklines, or color gradients)

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have the followng sample input:

```
WITH Ratings AS (
    (SELECT 'A' name, 2 score) UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'B' name, 0 score) UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'C' name, 5 score) UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'D' name, 1 score))
```

Where `score` is number between 0 and 5.
How can I produce a report showing names and corresponding number of stars  ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can build star rating as a string using two Unicode characters:

```
★ - Unicode code point 9733 
☆ - Unicode code point 9734
```

We can use [`CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#code_points_to_string) function to build the stars, and [`REPEAT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#repeat) function to produce the right number of stars

Combined together the solution for sample input will be:

```
WITH Ratings AS (
(SELECT 'A' name, 2 score) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'B' name, 0 score) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'C' name, 5 score) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'D' name, 1 score))

SELECT 
  name, 
  CONCAT(
    REPEAT(CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([9733]), score),
    REPEAT(CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([9734]), 5-score)) score
FROM Ratings
```

It will produce the following result:

```
name    score
A       ★★☆☆☆
B       ☆☆☆☆☆
C       ★★★★★
D       ★☆☆☆☆
```

Comment: Love this Mosha!

Answer (score 6):

My entry does a color gradient, because sparklines only look good with certain fonts - and that's not a font that the BigQuery web UI uses.

During a day, when is Stack Overflow the most active per tag:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION barchart(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>, mm STRUCT<min FLOAT64, max FLOAT64>) AS ((
    SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTR('', 1+CAST(ROUND(y) AS INT64), 1), '') 
    FROM (SELECT IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE((e-mm.min),(mm.max-mm.min))*4, 0) y FROM UNNEST(v) e))); 
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION vbar(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS ( 
  barchart(v, (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(a), MAX(a) FROM UNNEST(v) a)) 
);


WITH top_tags AS (
 (SELECT x.value FROM (SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(tag, 24) x FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`, UNNEST(SPLIT(tags,'|')) tag WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date)>=2016), UNNEST(x) x)
)

SELECT tag, vbar(ARRAY_AGG(1.0*hhh.count ORDER BY hhh.value)) gradient, SUM(hhh.count)  c
FROM (
  SELECT tag, APPROX_TOP_COUNT(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM creation_date), 24) h_h
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`, UNNEST(SPLIT(tags,'|')) tag
  WHERE tag IN (SELECT * FROM top_tags) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date)>=2016
  GROUP BY 1
), UNNEST(h_h) hhh
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY STRPOS(gradient, '')



Row gradient                                                c       tag  
1       317538  android  
2       59445   asp.net  
3       159134  ios  
4       111988  angularjs    
5       212843  jquery   
6       138143  mysql    
7       107586  swift    
8       318294  php  
9       84723   json     
10      233100  html     
11      390245  java     
12      83787   angular  
13      70150   sql-server   
14      534663  javascript   
15      291541  c#   
16      65668   c    
17      111792  sql  
18      158999  css  
19      88146   arrays   
20      61840   ruby-on-rails    
21      136265  c++  
22      104218  node.js  
23      360396  python   
24      98690   r
```

[image]

And a more compact shaded gradient, but with only 3 values:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION barchart(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>, mm STRUCT<min FLOAT64, max FLOAT64>) AS ((
    SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTR('▓▒░', 1+CAST(ROUND(y) AS INT64), 1), '') 
    FROM (SELECT IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE((e-mm.min),(mm.max-mm.min))*2, 0) y FROM UNNEST(v) e))); 
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION vbar(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS ( 
  barchart(v, (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(a), MAX(a) FROM UNNEST(v) a)) 
);



WITH top_countries AS (
 (SELECT x.value FROM (SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(country_code, 12) x FROM `ghtorrent-bq.ght_2017_09_01.users`), UNNEST(x) x)
)

SELECT vbar(ARRAY_AGG(1.0*hhh.count ORDER BY hhh.value)) gradient, SUM(hhh.count) c, country_code
FROM (
  SELECT country_code, APPROX_TOP_COUNT(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM a.created_at), 24) h_h
  FROM `githubarchive.year.2017` a
  JOIN `ghtorrent-bq.ght_2017_09_01.users` b
  ON a.actor.login=b.login
  WHERE country_code IN (SELECT * FROM top_countries) 
  AND actor.login NOT IN (SELECT value FROM (SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(actor.login, 1000) x FROM `githubarchive.year.2017` WHERE type='WatchEvent'), UNNEST(x))
  AND a.type='WatchEvent'
  GROUP BY 1
), UNNEST(h_h) hhh
GROUP BY country_code 
ORDER BY STRPOS(gradient, '░')

Row gradient                    c       country_code     
1   ░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░    204023  au   
2   ▒░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒    293589  jp   
3   ▓▒░░▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓    2125724 cn   
4   ▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓    447092  in   
5   ▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓    381510  ru   
6   ▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒    545906  de   
7   ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒    395949  fr   
8   ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒    491068  gb   
9   ▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒░░░░░▒▒▒    419608  br   
10  ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░░▒    2443381 us   
11  ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░░░░░░░▒▒    294793  ca
```

And a short code for sparklines - works great with Data Studio:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION barchart(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>, mm STRUCT<min FLOAT64, max FLOAT64>) AS ((
    SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTR('▁▂▃▄▅▆▇█', 1+CAST(ROUND(y) AS INT64), 1), '') 
    FROM (SELECT IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE((e-mm.min),(mm.max-mm.min))*7, 0) y FROM UNNEST(v) e))); 
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION vbar(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS ( 
  barchart(v, (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(a), MAX(a) FROM UNNEST(v) a)) 
);
```

Comment: forgot to say - love it! :o)

Answer (score 3):

Adding more-less generic option for producing time-series/sparklines type of report

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION sparklines(arr ARRAY<INT64>) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([code]), '') 
  FROM UNNEST(arr) el, 
  UNNEST([(SELECT MAX(el) FROM UNNEST(arr) el)]) mx, 
  UNNEST([(SELECT MIN(el) FROM UNNEST(arr) el)]) mn
  JOIN UNNEST([9602, 9603, 9605, 9606, 9607]) code WITH OFFSET pos
  ON pos = CAST(IF(mx = mn, 1, (el - mn) / (mx - mn)) * 4 AS INT64) 
)); 
WITH series AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [3453564, 5343333, 2876345, 3465234] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [5743231, 3276438, 1645738, 2453657] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, [3245876, 2342879, 5876324, 7342564]  
)  
SELECT 
  id, TO_JSON_STRING(arr) arr, sparklines(arr) sparklines 
FROM series
```

with result as below

```
Row id  arr                                 sparklines   
1   1   [3453564,5343333,2876345,3465234]   ▃▇▂▃     
2   2   [5743231,3276438,1645738,2453657]   ▇▅▂▃     
3   3   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]               ▂▃▃▅▅▆▆▇▇▂   
4   4   [3245876,2342879,5876324,7342564]   ▃▂▆▇
```

Adding Mosha's version (taken from his comments below)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION barchart(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>, MIN FLOAT64, MAX FLOAT64) AS ( 
  IF(
    MIN = MAX, 
    REPEAT(CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([9603]), ARRAY_LENGTH(v)), 
    (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([9601 + CAST(ROUND(y) AS INT64)]), '') 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(e-min, MAX - MIN) * 7 y 
      FROM UNNEST(v) e)
    )
  )
); 
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION vbar(v ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS ( 
  barchart(v, (SELECT MIN(a) FROM UNNEST(v) a), (SELECT MAX(a) FROM UNNEST(v) a)) 
);
WITH numbers AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [3453564., 5343333., 2876345., 3465234.] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [5743231., 3276438., 1645738., 2453657.] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, [1.,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, [3245876., 2342879, 5876324, 7342564]  
)  
SELECT 
  id, TO_JSON_STRING(arr) arr, vbar(arr) sparklines 
FROM numbers
```

if applied to same dummy data as above versions - produces below

```
Row id  arr                                 sparklines   
1   1   [3453564,5343333,2876345,3465234]   ▃█▁▃     
2   2   [5743231,3276438,1645738,2453657]   █▄▁▂     
3   3   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]               ▂▃▃▄▅▆▆▇█▁   
4   4   [3245876,2342879,5876324,7342564]   ▂▁▆█
```

Comment: Nice, but you need to protect against flatline, i.e. when max == min - your function will fail with division by zero. Here is my version of sparklines:

Comment: it is taken care of  - check the code :o) `IF(mx = mn, 1, (el - mn) / (mx - mn)) * 4`

Comment: My version of sparklines: create temp function barchart(v array<FLOAT64>, min FLOAT64, max FLOAT64) as (
  if (min = max, repeat(code_points_to_string([9603]), array_length(v)),
  (select string_agg(code_points_to_string([9601+CAST(ROUND(y) AS INT64)]), '') from (
  select safe_divide(e-min, max - min) * 7 y from unnest(v) e)))
);
create temp function vbar(v array<FLOAT64>)
as (
  barchart(v, (select min(a) from unnest(v) a), (select max(a) from unnest(v) a))
);

Comment: <commenting UX in SO is horrible/> I prefer my version because it avoids doing self JOIN of array

Comment: I found the problem with using all 7 or 8 unicodes starting with 9601. somehow they are not even when put together in one sparkline. So I picked only those which produce polished look

Comment: It depends on font - in some fonts they are even, in others - they are not :(

Comment: exactly, so I decided to be on safe side with appearance :o)

Comment: for fun, check the color gradient below inspired by the sparklines... (without a font problem)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - check for even more fun 

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - this is brilliant!

Comment: Thank you Mosha. Glad you liked it :o)

Answer (score 3):

More craziness here 
Totally useless  - but fun to play with

Applying all different options presented in this post for image processing and drawing (using profile pictures of those contribute into this post) + some new

---

[image][image]

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

[image]
[image]

---

1st and 2nd result (for Felipe's picture) produced using Felipe's `Color Gradient` approach with different scaling options

3rd result - using Felipe's `Shaded Gradient` approach

4th result - using Mikhail's(mine)/Mosha's `Spark-line` approach

Finally 5th and 6th results - using ASCII characters sets representing `ASCII Shades of Gray` - respectively:
    Short set - " `.:-=+*#%@`"
    Full (long) set - "``` $@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,"^``'. ``` "

Code is trivial and literally same as in respective answers - the only difference is that data used in above exercises is image's pixels data that is simply acquired using `HTML canvas getImageData() Method` - obviously outside of BigQuery - with just simple html page

Options for getting crazy here and having fun playing with image transformation / processing - limitless! but probably useless outside of just learning scope

Answer (score 0):

Fitting vertical bar chart into single character is challenging because there are only 8 different heights we could use. But horizontal bar charts don't have this limitation, we can scale horizontal chart by arbitrary length. Example below uses 30, and it shows number of births per day of week as horizontal bar chart. Data is based on public dataset:

```
create temp function hbar(value int64, max int64) as (
  repeat('█', cast(30 * value / max as int64))
);
select 
  ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday',
   'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'][ordinal(wday)] wday, bar from (
select wday, hbar(count(*), max(count(*)) over()) bar
from `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
where wday is not null
group by 1
order by 1 asc)
```

Results in

```
wday      bar
---------------------------------------------
sunday    ███████████████████
monday    ███████████████████████████
tuesday   ██████████████████████████████
wednesday ██████████████████████████████
thursday  █████████████████████████████
friday    █████████████████████████████
saturday  █████████████████████
```

Comment: shouldn't you edit and extend your existing answer with this? :)