# how to find highest value in a record in Google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table called sample. It contains companies profits. I would like to display the highest profit of each company in Google bigquery.

```
company   2014      2015      2016      2017
companyA  3453564   5343333   2876345   3465234
companyB  5743231   3276438   1645738   2453657
companyC  3245876   2342879   5876324   7342564
```

Any help thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and gives best profit value along with year and also has no dependency on number of year columns and their (columns) names

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.companies` AS (
  SELECT 'companyA' company, 3453564 year_2014, 5343333 year_2015, 2876345 year_2016, 3465234 year_2017 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'companyB', 5743231, 3276438, 1645738, 2453657 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'companyC', 3245876, 2342879, 5876324, 7342564 
)
SELECT 
  company,   
  highest_profit.*
FROM `project.dataset.companies` t, UNNEST(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] year,
      SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) profit
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), ',"')) kv
    ORDER BY profit DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
) highest_profit
```

with result as

```sql
Row company     year        profit   
1   companyA    year_2015   5343333  
2   companyB    year_2014   5743231  
3   companyC    year_2017   7342564
```

Update:  decided to borrow idea from Mosha's [`Star Rating`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48951848/5221944) post and apply it to time series here and adding kind of sparklines chart

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION sparklines(arr ARRAY<INT64>) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([code]), '') 
  FROM UNNEST(arr) el, 
  UNNEST([(SELECT MAX(el) FROM UNNEST(arr) el)]) mx, 
  UNNEST([(SELECT MIN(el) FROM UNNEST(arr) el)]) mn
  JOIN UNNEST([9602, 9603, 9605, 9606, 9607]) code WITH OFFSET pos
  ON pos = CAST(IF(mx = mn, 1, (el - mn) / (mx - mn)) * 4 AS INT64) 
)); 
WITH `project.dataset.companies` AS (
  SELECT 'companyA' company, 3453564 year_2014, 5343333 year_2015, 2876345 year_2016, 3465234 year_2017 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'companyB', 5743231, 3276438, 1645738, 2453657 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'companyC', 3245876, 2342879, 5876324, 7342564 
)
SELECT 
  company,   
  highest_profit.*,
  sparklines(
    ARRAY(
      SELECT SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) profit
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), ',"')) kv
      WHERE NOT SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) IS NULL
      ORDER BY SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)]
    )
  ) history
FROM `project.dataset.companies` t, UNNEST(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] year,
      SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'[{"}]', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) profit
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), ',"')) kv
    ORDER BY profit DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
) highest_profit
```

with result as below

```sql
Row company     year        profit      history  
1   companyA    year_2015   5343333     ▃▇▂▃     
2   companyB    year_2014   5743231     ▇▅▂▃     
3   companyC    year_2017   7342564     ▃▂▆▇
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is by using `GREATEST` (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#mathematical-functions)):

```
WITH
  input AS (
  SELECT
    'companyA' AS company,
    3453564 AS y2014,
    5343333 AS y2015,
    2876345 AS y2016,
    3465234 AS y2017
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'companyB' AS company,
    5743231 AS y2014,
    3276438 AS y2015,
    1645738 AS y2016,
    2453657 AS y2017
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'companyC' AS company,
    3245876 AS y2014,
    2342879 AS y2015,
    5876324 AS y2016,
    7342564 AS y2017)
SELECT
  company,
  GREATEST(y2014,y2015,y2016,y2017) AS max_profit
FROM
  input
```

Output:

```
Row company     max_profit   
1   companyA    5343333  
2   companyB    5743231  
3   companyC    7342564
```

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: It is working, I would also like to get year along with the max_profit.

Comment: Cool. But you never stated that in your original question David.